# Unresolved tag Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, tags

I'am working on an app that can download, modify, read, show and share PDF. To do this, I found a youtube video that use some external libraries on github. I tried to add to my project (especially in an xml file) a PDF Viewer from a repository that the video advised to use but when I run into a problem and I don't Know why. The program says that there is an "unresolvable tag" but I don't Know how to resolve it. I attach the full code below, thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:id="@+id/tcTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PDF Viewer Demo"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tcTitle"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/shareButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:text="SHARE PDF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    />

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: These are the solutions that Android Studio advices]

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you the `com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView` class isn't found, which means that you didn't import it into your project properly.

How did you include it in your project? Did you add use the following in your app gradle?

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:version'
```

Or did you download the source code, and import it into your poroject?

Comment: I use the dependecy in the build gradle but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Are you able to use the PDFView class in code?

Comment: What if you import the source directly into your project?

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle(:app) add

```
    implementation 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

in the

```
dependencies {}
```

block.

In gradle.properties add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Adding it before or after

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

will be ok. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to refactor menu and migrate to the project Android x it's working for me

And also implemented the dependency library as above comments mentioned